# what is the best method to bind dom events on website based on es6?

Tags: javascript

this days i build a custom website and i use es6 classes to perform most of the js work.
as i try to keep the site fast i do not use any js framework and try to keep it vanilla.

I wonder, what should be faster and more efficient to maintain, shall i just create lots of `document.addeventlistener` on single js file or shall i create class for binding events and use lile:

```
class dom_events {
    constructor() {
        document.body.addEventListener('click', this.clickHandler, false );
    }

    clickHandler = event => {
        // do stuff
        document.body.removeEventListener('click', this.clickHandler);
    }
}
```

or maybe using some "object" functions like:

```
var dom_events = {
bind: function(){
document.body.addEventListener('click', this.clickHandler, false );

}
}
```

moreover, shall i use one big file or is it better to use one js file for each module of the website?

since i'm about to bind about 500 events, i would love to hear from your knowledge and experience

Comment: This is both too broad a question as well as an opinionated one. Show us where you are having specific problems if you need help

Comment: Measure first and then make optimisations. You may find that 500 events is actually not an issue

Comment: @charlietfl - well there is no actual problem as i'm on the phase of deciding about the technology and i wonder what would work better

Comment: You ***might*** get a better response asking something like this on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/  but check the on topic  guidelines thoroughly first so you can frame your question to suit. It's still pretty broad and opinionated and off topic here for both reasons. Some of it simply boils down to personal preference

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, multiple js files can slow down your website because the browser sends different requests to the server. Also, if your js file is very large, then it might cause the same problem.

If you want to add multiple js files, you can use `<link rel="preload" href="path to your js file..." as="script">`.

If your js file is not very large, then you can use script tag in your HTML file. This reduces the load and makes your webpage faster.